# Regex to source code comments

Tags: c++, regex, comments

Is there a regular expression to match any line comment, but avoiding the comments inside strings?
I need all content in a line after `//` (with the `//` included)

For example:

```
//Comment (match!)
bla bla bla bla //Comment (match!)
this string "foo // foo" (don't match because it's inside "")
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this pure-regex

Comment: You can, as showcased by my answer. I was originally going to present a proof that the grammar is [context-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) rather than [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar), but I ended up creating [a finite automation](http://i.stack.imgur.com/b9wik.png), which recognizes the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

The following [regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/uJ8xC5/14) will correctly match any strings and regular expressions in the input:

```
var strings = /("((.|\\\n)*?([^\\"]|\\\\)|)"|'((.|\\\n)*?([^\\']|\\\\)|)'|\/[^*](.*([^\\\/]|\\\\))\/|\/\*\/)/g;
```

You can remove strings from the input and then match comments using [another regular expression](https://regex101.com/r/uJ8xC5/10):

```
var comments = /((\/\/)(.*)|(\/\*)((.|\n)*)(\*\/))/g;
input.replace(strings, "").match(comments);
```

```js
var strings = /("((.|\\\n)*?([^\\"]|\\\\)|)"|'((.|\\\n)*?([^\\']|\\\\)|)'|\/[^*](.*([^\\\/]|\\\\))\/|\/\*\/)/g,
    comments = /((\/\/)(.*)|(\/\*)((.|\n)*)(\*\/))/g;

function update() {
  var arr = input.value.replace(strings, "").match(comments);
  output.value = arr ? arr.join("\n") : "";
}

input.onkeydown = input.onkeyup = input.onchange = update;
update();
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 90%;
  height: 5em;
}
```

```html
<p>Input:</p>
<textarea id="input">
//Comment (match!)
bla bla bla bla //Comment (match!)
this string "foo // foo"
</textarea>

<p>Output:</p>
<textarea id="output">
</textarea>
```

Comment: Gives false positives, consider: { a + "//" + b }

Answer (score -1):

```
^[^"]*(//.*)
```

Will not catch all cases but at least your examples should work

Update: A `^` was missing at the beginning.

Comment: It will not work, even on the examples. `[^"]*` doesn't have to match anything because of the quantifier, so any double slash will match.

Comment: you can add closed strings delimited with "": ^([^"]|\"(\\\"|[^"])*\")*(//.*) considering that \" may appear inside a string

Answer (score -1):

This regex will work in all cases (see [regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/fT6tK5/1)):

`(("[^"]*){2})*(\/\/.*)`

You want anything matched by the third capture group. Alternately, you could make the first two groups non-capturing.

It works by skipping any even number of quotes followed by other text, before hitting double slashes.

Comment: And then a string like `"\""` comes along and it stops working.

Comment: You are correct. I added another solution that handles it an entirely different way, and handles all cases.

Comment: @Biffen: THIS answer does not handle it, but my OTHER answer does. Try it in regex101.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another solution that should catch every single-line comment (see it work on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uT8kI6/4)):

`(\/\/.*)|"(?:\\"|.)*?"`

All the comments will be captured in the first match group.

It will work in any regex flavor that has lazy quantifiers, which is almost all of them. The technique I used is to match quoted strings specifically so they get "removed" from the text available to match what we want: comments. This technique is explained in detail on RexEgg.com as [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).

Breakdown:

`(\/\/.*)` matches comments, and captures in group

`"(?:\\"|.)*?"` matches quoted strings, avoiding any escaped quotes inside

- The inside non-capturing group `(?:\\"|.)` matches an escaped quote OR the next character, successfully passing right over the escaped quotes rather than having them match as a "real" quote
- The whole alternation has the `*?` lazy quantifier so it hits the next "real" quote, rather than proceeding to another quoted string.