# Simple regex expression to detect comments (which are not inside string)

Tags: java, regex, comments

this might seem like a simple question, but i having trouble with regular expression. I need a regex that will detect // that is not inside quotations.

```
E.g:
//comment
String ex = "//I do not need to detect this";
```

Comment: Which lang you're running? Where is your attempts? What's the expected output?

Comment: Java. I will be using on String replacement. i managed to do till here: (?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$). I am new to regex expression.

Comment: Duplicate: [Regex to source code comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27534037/regex-to-source-code-comments)

Answer (score 0):

The regex `/\/\/((?:(?!\/\/)[^\n])+)$/gm` will capture all comments.

```
//comments here
String ex1 = "//I do not need to detect this"; //but I need this
String ex2 = "//I do not need to detect this";
String ex3 = "//I do not need to detect this";// this also
```

will return `comments here`, `but I need this`, and `this also` respectively.

Hope this is what you wanted!

Comment: Try the updated code, just edited my post. Are you able to add the custom flags? Not sure what program or language you're using this in, that's important.

Comment: I am using java.It still isn't working. I am having extra backslashes due to escape character.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by `I am having extra backslashes due to escape character.` but they are necessary to escape those characters. I only posted the raw regex, you shouldn't include the first / or the last /gm part when declaring the pattern, but you need to enable the `g` **and** the `m` flags for the pattern.

Comment: By the way, remove the C++ tag if you're using Java, tag Java instead.

Comment: I am using it for String replacement so it becomes like this: "/\\/\\/((?:(?!\\/\\/)[^\\n])+)$/gm"

Comment: You wouldn't include the first / or the last part with /gm, you should be using `"\\/\\/((?:(?!\\/\\/)[^\\n])+)$"`. Can you please post the entire line of code you're using for the regex? The entire .replace line or the pattern part, however you're using it.

Comment: `String text   = "//Comments\nString c =\"Hello world\" //Not needed";
 text = text.replaceAll("regex", "/*");`